# What do I have to change when I get the Circular Dependency Error with the code below?

Tags: dependencies, circular-dependency

I want to group various items within category, but when I try to group I get the Circular Dependency error about Item Group Code, I am using the code below to create the Item Group Code. Can someone figure out what I have to change to stop getting the Circular error and can group my graph? :)

```
Item Group Code = CALCULATE(MIN('Production Orders Lines'[Item Group Code]),'Production Orders Lines'[Line No.] = 10000,USERELATIONSHIP('Production Orders'[Prod. Order No.], 'Production Orders Lines'[Prod. Order No.]))
```

I already tried changing the code by rewriting it and changing code position which didn't work.